# Mask whole page when execute jQuery post?

Tags: ajax, jquery

In jQuery, is there any way to mask whole page automatically when we execute each Ajax post (to prevent input from user or double submitting...)? I see this plugin: jQuery-blockUI (http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) but we still have to mask/unmask manually for each Ajax post.
As I know in ExtJS, we can control this by implementing "beforeAction" function, because this event will be fired right before any action on form, but in jQuery I do not find out anything like that.
Could you please give me a solution for this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you check [$.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) man page (and its derivatives')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the beforeSend and complete functions

```
$.ajax({
  beforeSend: function() {
           //Mask page
    },
  complete: function(){
              //remove Mask
}
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

It wouldn't be too hard to do this yourself.

**HTML**

```
<body>
     <div id="mask"></div>
     <!-- Everything else -->
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#mask{
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background: /* You can make this slightly transparent black rgba(0,0,0,.3); or transparent */;
top:0;
left:0;
display:none;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var isPageMasked = false,
    mask = $('#mask');

var maskPage = function(){

    if(isPageMasked){
        mask.hide();
    } else {
        mask.show();
    }

    isPageMasked = !isPageMasked;

};
```

Then you would just call maskPage() when you make you want to mask and unmask the page.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Reza. But with this solution, I still have to call maskPage() before doing Ajax call and unmask page when request complete. It is not controlled automatically for each Ajax request.